# Nodejs use process.setuid for recently created user

Tags: node.js

I am creating a new user in the ubuntu system using nodejs with standard shell commands. After creating it process.setuid can not access to recently created user. But the user is being created in the system, I can get user id with id -u .

Only after re-starting node process I am able to access the user ID.

So right after creating a user with node process I need to switch to that user and use the local user privileges. But it seems node can only access the linux system user base during initial process start.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you add a delay of one second between creating and accessing user id? (Who knows, magic happens :) )

Comment: I have tried that, added 3 secs of delay. no success.